# How to join corresponding elements of lists in Python

Tags: python

I have a file with name `ids.txt` also file with name `names.txt`

in the `ids.txt` file we see:

```
23
422
5123
642
8743
```

the content of the `names.txt` file:

```
jon1
jon2
jon3
jon4
jon5
```

I want to sort it like this:

```
23 jon1
422 jon2
5123 jon3
642 jon4
8743 jon5;
```

and when it's sorted the last one set it like this

```
8743 jon5;
```

what I'm doing is :

```
IDs = file("IDs.txt").read().splitlines()
names = file("names-specialitys.txt").read().splitlines()
for i in IDs:
    for n in names:
        print i, n
```

but it's print it like this:

```
23 jon1
422 jon1
5123 jon1
642 jon1
8743 jon1
23 jon2
```

... etc

Comment: `zip` the two lists.

Comment: In your question you say 'sort', but the list [22, 422, 5123, 642, ...] is not sorted (in ascending or descending order anyway!). I think you mean that you want to pair the items in the two lists together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) the lists together.

```
for i, n in zip(IDs, names):
    print i, n
```

To display the last row differently, you could slice the lists before you zip them. Then print the last row separately.

```
for i, n in list(zip(IDs[:-1], names[:-1]):
    print("{} {}".format(i, n))
print("{} {};".format(IDs[-1], names[-1]))
```

Comment: and how can I know the last line in this file, and set ";" at the end of print

Comment: like this at the end : 8743 jon5;

Answer (score 1):

## "Zip"y explanation:

Python has a great `zip()` function built in. It takes 2 lists, and joins each item with the item at the same point in an array.

## Example:

```
a = b = c = range(20)
zip(a, b, c) #=> [(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), ... (18, 18, 18), (19, 19, 19)]
```

## Your Solution:

```
for i, n in zip(IDs, names):
    print i + " " + n
```